# How to use @ symbol in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I'm using @ in Razor MVC -as text- I get a parse error:

```
"&" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
```

There must be something simple about this, can't figure it out.

The code:

```
<p><b>2011</b> <a target="_blank" href="http://www.blabla.nl">blabla</a>w/ @twittername<br />Done 12/2011</p>
```

Comment: Show us the line where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to use the HTML code `&#64;`

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it was to easy... Stupid me :)

Use @@

Answer (score 2):

Use like

```
@@
```

It will work sure.